# Get the value/text of a column in a Gridview in ASP.net C# to display in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` that has a list of *Salesman* names. When a Salesman is selected using A `ButtonFieldTemplate` in the `Grid`. I need the name of selected Salesman to appear in a `Label`.

So far I have this but it is not working:

```
protected void gvSalesmanByManager_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = gvSalesmanByManager.SelectedValue + "'s Customers"; 
}
```

It's not throwing any errors. Not even red squiggly lines in Visual Studio. It's just plain not working.

How can I accomplish this in ASP.net and C# 4.0.

Comment: Can we see what code you have so far with the event and everything?

Comment: My code so far :   protected void gvSalesmanByManager_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
      
       
        lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = gvSalesmanByManager.SelectedValue + "'s Customers";

    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedvalue.aspx) SelectedValue gets the data key value of the selected row in a GridView control. Does your GridView contain a column with the key and did you set the dataKeyNamesProperty (such as datakeynames="myID")?

EDIT:
To access a value of a column you can use SelectedRow:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
```

EDIT2:
There are two options when you want to read the template field. Either you store your value in an additional invisible column or you access the controls inside the template field. Something like this should work:

```
lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].FindContol("tbxName")).Text;
```

Comment: It does contain the Key and I did set the DataKey names. However I am not trying to Get the Key/ID, I am actually trying to get 2 columns over for the Name of the Salesman. Unless I need to get the Key first and the get the text from 2 columns over?

Comment: Use selectetRow like in my updated sample to access other values

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This is getting me closer. I can now get the value of a particular cell in a column. It works with the 1st cell, 2nd cell, 3, cell, but of course when I try the fouth cell(The name of the salesman) it fails. It shows nothing. That particular cell is a Template field: Link Button. It also concats in the Stored Procedure the persons first and last name. Could these things be causing a problem? I'm thinking because it is a template field: LinkButton, it doesn't want to work. I am getting closer though.

Comment: Yeah. The template field is getting in the way. I just changed it back to ta bound field and it works fine. Arrg. This field needs to be clickable.

Comment: See my adjusted solution. You can always search for the control.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not assigning empty text on page load event.
or you need to place those initialization in if(!Page.IsPostback) block

Comment: Ok. Your comment helped... a little. I was inside the PageLoad Event. So I moved it to the SelectedIndex changed event for the grid I am clicking on. Now I get the Label to read "14's Customers". When It should say "Frank's Customers" Obviously it is getting the IndividualID/Key from the data grid. How do I get the text from 2 columns over? The guys actual name to appear in the label?

Comment: The current Data Key name is: IndividualID. This Key Brings up a datagrid of customers That belong to the Salesman with that IndividualID. But I also need to get the Name of that salesman to appear in a Label when the Goid is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

My code so far : protected void gvSalesmanByManager_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = gvSalesmanByManager.SelectedValue + "'s Customers"; } –

try in the event "gvSalesmanByManager_SelectedIndexChanged" following code:

lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = gvSalesmanByManager.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

You said something about a "ButtonFieldTemplate" please show me some code from your ascx-file this will help us much i think.

*Edit:
"Controls[1]" has not to be right. But 0 is a literal. you could also debug your code and set breakpoints. would be much easier.
try this with Linkbutton:
LinkButton lnk1 = gvSalesmanByManager.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[1] as LinkButton;
lblSalesmanCustomers.Text = lnk1.Text;

best regards,
noone

Comment: slfan's comments above are working, however I cannot get the text of the buttonfield to appear in the label. Only a BoundField. Here is my Aspx page code: <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="SalesPerson"  HeaderText="Sales Person" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Select"  />